# How to use the counter in a for loop as a number to define a new array

Tags: r, counter

To make it simple: How can i change this expression?

`for (i in 1:5){ai=i}`

in a way that in "ai" the i is interpreted as a counter and not as a letter "i",
so that it creates

`a1=1, a2=2,...`

I remember a language where you could just use $i to solve this

`for (i in 1:5){a$i=i}`

but i didn't find the equivalent in R, can someone help me ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assign`

```
for (i in 1:5) 
  assign(paste0("a", i), i)
```

but I do not recommend this approach. You can use a vector or a list instead:

```
a <- list()
for (i in 1:5)
  a <- append(a, i)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer,
but my problem is more complex, as I want to extract from a matrix of points (labelled X,Y,Z and Time) to make a vector x1 for time 1 containing all the x positions of time 1, another one for time 2 and so on.
So instead of having just a number i for each position, it will be a vector of different length for each time.

Comment: @Aure I updated the second part of my answer (now, a list is used).

Comment: @SvenHohenstein You have a small typo in the list answer. You forgot the parenthesis after `list` when you initialize `a`.

Answer (score 0):

in C++ it is done as:

```
a[i] = i;
```

where `a[i]` signifies i+1th element in array

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
a <- NULL
for (i in 1:5) a[i] <- i
```